# Express stylesheet 404 error when there is a parameter in the url

Tags: css, node.js, express, parameters, pug

Using express 3.5.1 on localhost
I have in my app.js file

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

and my style.css file is in public/stylesheets

In my page.jade file I have

```
doctype html
html
    head
        link(rel = "stylesheet" href = "stylesheets/style.css")
    body
        // more stuff here
```

And finally, in my routes I have

```
app.get('/path', dostuff);
app.get('/path/:param', dostuff);

function dostuff(req,res) {
    res.render('page');
}
```

Now, when I go to localhost:3000/path, everything is fine and style.css is included. But I go to localhost:3000/path/anything, the page still renders, but I'm getting 404 errors for any stylesheets I happen to include, even though the function is exactly the same. Why would this be? Did some poking around couldn't seem to find an answer for this specific case.

Answer (score 7):

For `http://localhost:3000/path/foo`, the browser uses `http://localhost:3000/path` as the base URL, so it's trying to request `http://localhost:3000/path/stylesheets/style.css` because `stylesheets/style.css` is a relative link. Prefix it with a `/` to turn it into an absolute link instead...

```
link(rel = "stylesheet" href = "/stylesheets/style.css")
```

Comment: Doh! I should have noticed that when I looked at the console. Thanks for the fast answer.

Comment: got the same problem and it was working great with you solution. thank you!

Comment: This is the exact solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your stylesheet href is relative and the browser sees a request for `/path/anything` so it tacks on `/stylesheets/style.css` to the end. The browser does not know that it's the same page and that `anything` is just a rewritten query parameter.

Two possible solutions:

1. Use absolute paths. If you use nested routers in Express 4, you can actually now get the base path of the current router. This could help you build the path for your stylesheets if you still want them to be relative to whatever route(s).
2. Use actual query parameter(s) like `/path?param=anything`.

Comment: Used the second method. Works like a charm! Thanks a ton! Cheers! :)